# Avira : Realtime protection settings - archive extension

Tags: virus, zip, anti-virus, rar, avira

These are two images from avira real-protection settings.

[image]
[image]

1st question) In this setting, does avira scan zip/rar or not scan zip/rar ?

2nd question) What if I remove .zip and .rar in File extension list, and check v in 'Scan archives'?